# Is my observation in a lecture about Kolmogorov–Smirnov test correct?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I'm reading Kolmogorov–Smirnov test from a [lecture note](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-443-statistics-for-applications-fall-2006/lecture-notes/lecture14.pdf) from MIT OpenCourseWare [Statistics for Applications](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-443-statistics-for-applications-fall-2006/). In the lecture note, there are two important theorems:

> [image]

and

> [image]

It seems to me that $H(t) > 0$ for all $t \in \mathbb R$. However, $$\mathbb{P}\left(\sqrt{n} \sup _{x \in \mathbb{R}}\left|F_{n}(x)-F(x)\right| \leq t\right) = 0$$ for all $t < 0$. As such, I feel that **Theorem 2** holds only for $t \ge 0$.

Could you please verify if my observation is correct?

Comment: When $t\le 0$ the right hand side is undefined.  The author assumes you understand that when an absolute value is compared to $t,$ you are only concerned about the case $t\ge 0$ and will interpret Theorem 2 accordingly (which indeed is incorrect when $t=0$). That may be a little sloppy, but anyone learning about the K-S distribution presumably has the mathematical sophistication not to be confused by that.

Comment: Hi @whuber, I thought it's clear that $$\mathbb{P}\left(\sqrt{n} \sup _{x \in \mathbb{R}}\left|F_{n}(x)-F(x)\right| \leq t\right) = 0$$ Could you please explain why it's undefined for $t \ge 0$?

Comment: That's the opposite of what I wrote: the sum obviously diverges when $t$ is *negative,* not when it's positive. The proof is that for $i\gt 1/\sqrt{-t/2}$ each term exceeds $1$ in absolute value.

Comment: @whuber the c.d.f in this lecture note is indeed incorrect. It follows from this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3579194/which-one-of-these-two-functions-is-the-c-d-f-of-kolmogorov-smirnov-distribution) that the correct one is $$H(t)= 1-2 \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{j-1} e^{-2 j^{2} t^2}$$ As such, $H$ is an even function.